# Evernote alternative

Tags: webapp-rec

Been using Evernote for two years and as much as I love the ease of use and Twitter integration I find the UI ugly and hard to use.

Anybody know of an alternative with social media and email integration?

Please limit your answers to apps that are under active development.

Comment: Just wondering, because I like Evernote and don't have problems with the interface, what do you not like about their interface? Is it just their desktop app or something else?

Comment: I agree with the UI sentiment shared above. IMO, the biggest detractor from it is how slow it is to move around inside the application. The UI loads slowly and individual notes take time to render. Difficult to justify if you want to quickly get at some piece of information.

Comment: @Daryll Ah, I meant the web app. It's hard to do simple stuff like tagging multiple entries. The ease of entry is what won me over. Managing stuff on the other hand is a PITA.

@Michael My thoughts exactly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Memonic](http://www.memonic.com/)
- [reQall](http://www.reqall.com/)
- [diigo](http://www.diigo.com/)

All have iOS apps; reQall and diigo have Android apps, as well.

Comment: I can recommend diigo - and if you use chrome it has an awesome plugin :)

Comment: diigo seems nice, I'll give it a spin.

Comment: reQall sounds promising. Thanks :D I tried using Diigo once and abandoned it for some reason. Time to check it out again I guess.

Answer (score 7):

**[Microsoft's OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/)**

I would suggest [Microsoft's OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/).  Although this is a pay-for desktop app, you can use the [online webapp version of OneNote for free at http://office.live.com/](http://office.live.com/).  You also get 25GB of storage with the free SkyDrive account, which is far more than what Evernote gives you free, and the interface is absolutely amazing*.

- NOTE: Amazing if you're a windows user, as the desktop version is not available for Mac, and the webapp requires IE for full desktop-like editing functionality.

Comment: Liked OneNote too but I barely use IE now. :(

Comment: I feel your pain.  :-/  I cry a little when I'm forced to use it for some Microsoft web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Clipmarks](http://clipmarks.com/), has more social media integration. Another alternative would be [springpad](http://springpadit.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Notebook](http://www.google.com/notebook). Quite unpopular, I don't know why. But good.

Comment: Guess the unpopularity is because Google decided that it wouldn't develop the Notebook further. No more feature updates

Comment: Get it now. But if this isn't a useful answer, the question should be updated to ask only for apps that are further developed, not ones that already have the features and have stopped developing.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for that @Slavo.

Comment: Google Notebook no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, I use Memonic a lot. Works well and has a Chrome plugin. You can sort and archive stuff easily and they are working on a "Read it later" type of functionality too.

Sorry, would be a comment, but not enough points for commenting yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use seesmic with evernote if you want social media intergration

http://blog.evernote.com/2010/05/21/seesmic-and-evernote-bring-social-memory-to-your-iphone-and-android-too/

Comment: Doesn't it have Twitter integration by default?